# FFMPEG produces audio bitrate lower than requested, when transcoding an mp4 file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

FFMPEG produces audio bitrate lower than requested, when transcoding an mp4 video file
I'm executing the following command:

```bash
ffmpeg -i base.mp4 -ac 2 -b:a 192k -minrate:a 192k -c:a aac -strict experimental 192k.mp4
```

Then I run `ffprobe` as follows:

```bash
ffprobe -bitexact 192k.mp4
```

```
ffprobe version 4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '192k.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    title           : <REDACTED>
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:15.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2673 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 2475 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 188 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

I specifically requested audio bitrate of 192kbps in the command above, but the audio stream looks like it has 188kbps:
`Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp,` **`188 kb/s`** `(default)`.
I don't understand why and how can I ensure it produces what I requested.
I searched the documentation and forums, but I don't see anyone complaining about this specific issues, and everything points to just using `-b:a 192k` with a possible addition of `-minrate:a 192k`.

How can I ensure minimum audio bitrate using ffmpeg?

Comment: There is a certain bitrate limit that the encoded stream cannot exceed (the limit is data dependent). When the data (audio) is compressed well, it is not going to reach `192k`. You may try `192M` instead of `192k` and it's probably still going to be 188 kb/s.

Comment: After specifying 200k, it gave me 195k in the resulting file. I wonder if there's a way to ensure a predictable result. I've been reading about constant bit rate in the documentation, however I can't figure out how to make it to actually produce the specific kbps.

Comment: According to the documentation for constant bit rate, use: `-b:a 192k -minrate:a 192k -maxrate:a 192k` (maybe it supposed to work just for video - not for audio). You may also try **two pass encoding** (but maybe it's relevant only for video).